# Running multiple requestAnimation loops to fire multiple balls?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the ball below to keep appearing and firing up accross the y axis at a set interval and always from where the x position of paddle(mouse) is, i need there to be a delay between each ball firing. I'm trying to make space invaders but with the ball constantly firing at a set interval.

Do I need to create multiple requestAnimationFrame loops for each ball? Can someone help with a very basic example of how this should be done please or link a good article? I am stuck at creating an array for each ball and not sure how to architect the loop to achieve this effect. All the examples I can find are too complex

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    canvas {
      background: #eee;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 30%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="400"></canvas>

  <script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //start the requestAnimationFrame loop
    var myRequestAnimation;
    var myRequestAnimationBall;
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame;
    drawLoop();
    setInterval(drawBallLoop, 400);

    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height - 30;
    var defaultSpeedX = 0;
    var defaultSpeedY = 4;
    var dx = defaultSpeedX;
    var dy = -defaultSpeedY;
    var ballRadius = 10;

    var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;

    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 70;

    //control stuff
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;

    var brickRowCount = 1;
    var brickColumnCount = 1;
    var brickWidth = 40;
    var brickHeight = 20;
    var brickPadding = 10;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickOffsetLeft = 30;

    var score = 0;
    var lives = 3;



  

    //paddle
    function drawPaddle() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }

    //bricks
    function drawBricks() {
      for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
          if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
            var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
            var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
            bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
            bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //collision detection
    function collisionDetection() {
      for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
          var b = bricks[c][r];
          if (b.status == 1) {
            if (x > b.x && x < b.x + brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y + brickHeight) {
              dy = -dy;
              b.status = 0;
              score++;
              console.log(score);
              if (score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
                console.log("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
                window.cancelAnimationFrame(myRequestAnimation);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //default bricks
    var bricks = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
      bricks[c] = [];
      for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
        bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
      }
    }

    //lives
    function drawLives() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, canvas.width - 65, 20);
    }


    // ball1
    var ball1 = {
      x,
      y,
      directionX: 0,
      directionY: -5
    }

    // ball1
    var ball2 = {
      x,
      y,
      directionX: 0,
      directionY: -2
    }

    // put each ball in a balls[] array
    var balls = [ball1, ball2];

    
    function drawBall() {
      // clearCanvas();
      for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        var ball = balls[i]

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }

    ///////DRAW BALL LOOP////////
    function drawBallLoop() {
      myRequestAnimationBall = requestAnimationFrame(drawBallLoop);

      // clear frame
      //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      //draw ball
      drawBall();

      //move balls
      for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        balls[i].y += balls[i].directionY;
      }
    }

    //Clear Canvas
    function clearCanvas() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }





    ///////DRAW MAIN LOOP////////
    function drawLoop() {
      myRequestAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(drawLoop);

      // clear frame
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      //draw ball
      drawPaddle();
      drawBricks();
      collisionDetection();
      drawLives();


      //bounce off walls
      if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
      }

      if (rightPressed) {
        paddleX += 7;
        if (paddleX + paddleWidth > canvas.width) {
          paddleX = canvas.width - paddleWidth;
        }
      }

      else if (leftPressed) {
        paddleX -= 7;
        if (paddleX < 0) {
          paddleX = 0;
        }
      }
    }


    //keyboard left/right logic
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
    function keyDownHandler(e) {
      if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
      }
      else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
      }
    }
    function keyUpHandler(e) {
      if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
      }
      else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
      }
    }

    //relative mouse pos
    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), // abs. size of element
        scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width,    // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
        scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;  // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y

      return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX,   // scale mouse coordinates after they have
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY     // been adjusted to be relative to element
      }
    }

    //mouse movemment
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

    function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
      var mouseX = getMousePos(canvas, e).x;
      //e.clientX = the horizontal mouse position in the viewport
      //canvas.offsetLeft = the distance between the left edge of the canvas and left edge of the viewport
      var relativeX = mouseX;
      // console.log('mouse= ',relativeX, canvas.offsetLeft)
      // console.log('paddle= ', paddleX);
      // console.log(getMousePos(canvas, e).x);

      if (relativeX - (paddleWidth / 2) > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width - (paddleWidth / 2)) {
        paddleX = relativeX - (paddleWidth / 2);
      }
    }


  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Basic principles

Here's one way you could do it:

1. you need a `Game` object that will handle the update logic, store all current entities, deal with the game loop... IMO, this is where you should keep track of when was the last `Ball` fired and whether to fire a new one.

   In this demo, this object also handles current time, delta time, and requesting animation frames, but some might argue that this logic could be externalised, and just call some sort of `Game.update(deltaTime)` on each frame.

---

2. you need different objects for all entities in your game. I created an `Entity` class because I want to make sure *all* game entities have the minimum required to function (ie. update, draw, x, y...).

   There is a `Ball` class that `extends Entity` and is responsible for knowing it's own parameters (speed, size, ...), how to update and draw itself, ...

   There is a `Paddle` class that I left bare for you to complete.

---

The bottom line is it's all a matter of separation of concerns. Who should know what about whom? And then pass variables around.

---

As for your other question:

> Do I need to create multiple requestAnimationFrame loops for each ball?

It's definitely possible, but I'd argue that having a centralized place that handles `lastUpdate`, `deltaTime`, `lastBallCreated` makes things much simpler. And in practice, devs tends to try and have a single animation frame loop for this.

```js
class Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    update() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an update() function`) }
    draw() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs a draw() function`) }
    isDead() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an isDead() function`) }
}

class Ball extends Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super(x, y)
        this.speed = 100 // px per second
        this.size = 10 // radius in px
    }

    update(deltaTime) {
        this.y -= this.speed * deltaTime / 1000 // deltaTime is ms so we divide by 1000
    }

    /** @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context */
    draw(context) {
        context.beginPath()
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        context.fill()
    }

    isDead() {
        return this.y < 0 - this.size
    }
}

class Paddle extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super(0, 0)
    }

    update() { /**/ }
    draw() { /**/ }
    isDead() { return false }
}

class Game {
    /** @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas */
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.entities = [] // contains all game entities (Balls, Paddles, ...)
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        this.newBallInterval = 1000 // ms between each ball
        this.lastBallCreated = 0 // timestamp of last time a ball was launched
    }

    start() {
        this.lastUpdate = performance.now()
        const paddle = new Paddle()
        this.entities.push(paddle)
        this.loop()
    }

    update() {
        // calculate time elapsed
        const newTime = performance.now()
        const deltaTime = newTime - this.lastUpdate

        // update every entity
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.update(deltaTime))

        // other update logic (here, create new entities)
        if(this.lastBallCreated + this.newBallInterval < newTime) {
            const ball = new Ball(100, 300) // this is quick and dirty, you should put some more thought into `x` and `y` here
            this.entities.push(ball)
            this.lastBallCreated = newTime
        }

        // remember current time for next update
        this.lastUpdate = newTime
    }

    draw() {
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.draw(this.context))
    }

    cleanup() {
        // to prevent memory leak, don't forget to cleanup dead entities
        this.entities.forEach(entity => {
            if(entity.isDead()) {
                const index = this.entities.indexOf(entity)
                this.entities.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    }

    loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.context.canvas.width, this.context.canvas.height)
            this.update()
            this.draw()
            this.cleanup()
            this.loop()
        })
    }
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const game = new Game(canvas)
game.start()
```

```html
<canvas height="300" width="300"></canvas>
```

---

## Managing player inputs

Now let's say you want to add keyboard inputs to your game. In that case, I'd actually create a separate class, because depending on how many "buttons" you want to support, it can get very complicated very quick.

So first, let's draw a basic paddle so we can see what's happening:

```
class Paddle extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        // we just add a default initial x,y and height,width
        super(150, 20)
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 10
    }

    update() { /**/ }

    /** @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context */
    draw(context) { 
        // we just draw a simple rectangle centered on x,y
        context.beginPath()
        context.rect(this.x - this.width / 2, this.y - this.height / 2, this.width, this.height)
        context.fill()
    }

    isDead() { return false }
}
```

And now we add a basic `InputsManager` class that you can make as complicated as you want. Just for two keys, handling `keydown` and `keyup` and the fact that two keys can be pressed at once it already a few lines of code so it's good to keep things separate so as to not clutter our `Game` object.

```
class InputsManager {
    constructor() {
        this.direction = 0 // this is the value we actually need in out Game object
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeydown.bind(this))
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyup.bind(this))
    }

    onKeydown(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                this.direction = -1
                break
            case 'ArrowRight':
                this.direction = 1
                break
        }
    }

    onKeyup(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                if(this.direction === -1) // make sure the direction was set by this key before resetting it
                    this.direction = 0
                break
            case 'ArrowRight':
                this.direction = 1
                if(this.direction === 1) // make sure the direction was set by this key before resetting it
                    this.direction = 0
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we can update our `Game` class to make use of this new `InputsManager`

```
class Game {

    // ...

    start() {
        // ...
        this.inputsManager = new InputsManager()
        this.loop()
    }

    update() {
        // update every entity
        const frameData = {
            deltaTime,
            inputs: this.inputsManager,
        } // we now pass more data to the update method so that entities that need to can also read from our InputsManager
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.update(frameData))
    }

    // ...

}
```

And after updating the code for the `update` methods of our entities to actually use the new `InputsManager`, here's the result:

```js
class Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    update() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an update() function`) }
    draw() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs a draw() function`) }
    isDead() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an isDead() function`) }
}

class Ball extends Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super(x, y)
        this.speed = 300 // px per second
        this.radius = 10 // radius in px
    }

    update({deltaTime}) {
    // Ball still only needs deltaTime to calculate its update
        this.y -= this.speed * deltaTime / 1000 // deltaTime is ms so we divide by 1000
    }

    /** @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context */
    draw(context) {
        context.beginPath()
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        context.fill()
    }

    isDead() {
        return this.y < 0 - this.radius
    }
}

class Paddle extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super(150, 50)
        this.speed = 200
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 10
    }

    update({deltaTime, inputs}) {
    // Paddle needs to read both deltaTime and inputs
        this.x += this.speed * deltaTime / 1000 * inputs.direction
    }

    /** @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context */
    draw(context) { 
        context.beginPath()
        context.rect(this.x - this.width / 2, this.y - this.height / 2, this.width, this.height)
        context.fill()
    }

    isDead() { return false }
}

class InputsManager {
    constructor() {
        this.direction = 0
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeydown.bind(this))
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyup.bind(this))
    }

    onKeydown(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                this.direction = -1
                break
            case 'ArrowRight':
                this.direction = 1
                break
        }
    }

    onKeyup(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                if(this.direction === -1) 
                    this.direction = 0
                break
            case 'ArrowRight':
                this.direction = 1
                if(this.direction === 1)
                    this.direction = 0
                break
        }
    }
}

class Game {
    /** @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas */
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.entities = [] // contains all game entities (Balls, Paddles, ...)
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        this.newBallInterval = 500 // ms between each ball
        this.lastBallCreated = -Infinity // timestamp of last time a ball was launched
    }

    start() {
        this.lastUpdate = performance.now()
    // we store the new Paddle in this.player so we can read from it later
        this.player = new Paddle()
    // but we still add it to the entities list so it gets updated like every other Entity
        this.entities.push(this.player)
        this.inputsManager = new InputsManager()
        this.loop()
    }

    update() {
        // calculate time elapsed
        const newTime = performance.now()
        const deltaTime = newTime - this.lastUpdate

        // update every entity
        const frameData = {
            deltaTime,
            inputs: this.inputsManager,
        }
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.update(frameData))

        // other update logic (here, create new entities)
        if(this.lastBallCreated + this.newBallInterval < newTime) {
        // we can now read from this.player to the the position of where to fire a Ball
            const ball = new Ball(this.player.x, 300)
            this.entities.push(ball)
            this.lastBallCreated = newTime
        }

        // remember current time for next update
        this.lastUpdate = newTime
    }

    draw() {
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.draw(this.context))
    }

    cleanup() {
        // to prevent memory leak, don't forget to cleanup dead entities
        this.entities.forEach(entity => {
            if(entity.isDead()) {
                const index = this.entities.indexOf(entity)
                this.entities.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    }

    loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.context.canvas.width, this.context.canvas.height)
            this.update()
            this.draw()
            this.cleanup()
            this.loop()
        })
    }
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const game = new Game(canvas)
game.start()
```

```html
<canvas height="300" width="300"></canvas>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Once you click "Run code snippet", you have to click on the iframe to focus it so it can listen for keyboard inputs (arrow left, arrow right).

As a bonus, since we are now able to draw and move the paddle, I added the ability to create a Ball at the same `x` coordinate as the paddle. You can read the comments I left in the code snippet above for a quick explanation as to how this works.

---

## How to add functionality

Now I want to give you a more general outlook at how to approach future problems you might have when expending on this example. I'll take the example of wanting to test for collision between two game objects. You should ask yourself **where to place the logic?**

1. where is a place that *all* game objects can share logic? (creating the information)
2. where will you need to know about collisions? (accessing the information)

In this example, all game objects are sub classes of `Entity` so to me this makes sense to put the code there:

```
class Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.collision = 'none'
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    update() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an update() function`) }
    draw() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs a draw() function`) }
    isDead() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an isDead() function`) }

    static testCollision(a, b) {
        if(a.collision === 'none') {
            console.warn(`${a.constructor.name} needs a collision type`)
            return undefined
        }
        if(b.collision === 'none') {
            console.warn(`${b.constructor.name} needs a collision type`)
            return undefined
        }
        if(a.collision === 'circle' && b.collision === 'circle') {
            return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)**2 + (a.y - b.y)**2) < a.radius + b.radius
        }
        if(a.collision === 'circle' && b.collision === 'rect' || a.collision === 'rect' && b.collision === 'circle') {
            let circle = a.collision === 'circle' ? a : b
            let rect = a.collision === 'rect' ? a : b
            // this is a waaaaaay simplified collision that just works in this case (circle always comes from the bottom)
            const topOfBallIsAboveBottomOfRect = circle.y - circle.radius <= rect.y + rect.height / 2
            const bottomOfBallIsBelowTopOfRect = circle.y + circle.radius >= rect.y - rect.height / 2
            const ballIsRightOfRectLeftSide = circle.x + circle.radius >= rect.x - rect.width / 2
            const ballIsLeftOfRectRightSide = circle.x - circle.radius <= rect.x + rect.width / 2
            return topOfBallIsAboveBottomOfRect && bottomOfBallIsBelowTopOfRect && ballIsRightOfRectLeftSide && ballIsLeftOfRectRightSide
        }
        console.warn(`there is no collision function defined for a ${a.collision} and a ${b.collision}`)
        return undefined
    }
}
```

Now there are many kinds of 2D collisions so the code is a bit verbose, but the main point is: this is a design decision that I'm making here. **I can be generalist and future proof this** but then it looks like the above... And I have to add a `.collision` property to all of my game objects so that they know whether they should be treated as a `'circle'` or a '`rect'` in the above algorithm.

```
class Ball extends Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super(x, y)
        this.collision = 'circle'
    }
    // ...
}

class Paddle extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super(150, 50)
        this.collision = 'rect'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or I can be minimalist and just add what I need, in which case it might make more sense to actually put the code in the `Paddle` entity:

```
class Paddle extends Entity {
    testBallCollision(ball) {
        const topOfBallIsAboveBottomOfRect = ball.y - ball.radius <= this.y + this.height / 2
        const bottomOfBallIsBelowTopOfRect = ball.y + ball.radius >= this.y - this.height / 2
        const ballIsRightOfRectLeftSide = ball.x + ball.radius >= this.x - this.width / 2
        const ballIsLeftOfRectRightSide = ball.x - ball.radius <= this.x + this.width / 2
        return topOfBallIsAboveBottomOfRect && bottomOfBallIsBelowTopOfRect && ballIsRightOfRectLeftSide && ballIsLeftOfRectRightSide
    }
}
```

Either way, I now have access to the collision information from the `cleanup` function the `Game` loop (where I chose to place the logic of removing dead entities).

With my first *generalist* solution, I would use it like this:

```
class Game {
    cleanup() {
        this.entities.forEach(entity => {
            // I'm passing this.player so all entities can test for collision with the player
            if(entity.isDead(this.player)) {
                const index = this.entities.indexOf(entity)
                this.entities.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    }
}

class Ball extends Entity {
    isDead(player) {
        // this is the "out of bounds" test we already had
        const outOfBounds = this.y < 0 - this.radius
        // this is the new "collision with player paddle"
        const collidesWithPlayer = Entity.testCollision(player, this)
        return outOfBounds || collidesWithPlayer
    }
}
```

With the second *minimalist* approach, I'd still have to pass the player around for the test:

```
class Game {
    cleanup() {
        this.entities.forEach(entity => {
            // I'm passing this.player so all entities can test for collision with the player
            if(entity.isDead(this.player)) {
                const index = this.entities.indexOf(entity)
                this.entities.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    }
}

class Ball extends Entity {
    isDead(player) {
        // this is the "out of bounds" test we already had
        const outOfBounds = this.y < 0 - this.radius
        // this is the new "collision with player paddle"
        const collidesWithPlayer = player.testBallCollision(this)
        return outOfBounds || collidesWithPlayer
    }
}
```

---

## Final result

I hope you've learned something. In the mean time, here's the final result of this very long answer post:

```js
class Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.collision = 'none'
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    update() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an update() function`) }
    draw() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs a draw() function`) }
    isDead() { console.warn(`${this.constructor.name} needs an isDead() function`) }

    static testCollision(a, b) {
        if(a.collision === 'none') {
            console.warn(`${a.constructor.name} needs a collision type`)
            return undefined
        }
        if(b.collision === 'none') {
            console.warn(`${b.constructor.name} needs a collision type`)
            return undefined
        }
        if(a.collision === 'circle' && b.collision === 'circle') {
            return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)**2 + (a.y - b.y)**2) < a.radius + b.radius
        }
        if(a.collision === 'circle' && b.collision === 'rect' || a.collision === 'rect' && b.collision === 'circle') {
            let circle = a.collision === 'circle' ? a : b
            let rect = a.collision === 'rect' ? a : b
            // this is a waaaaaay simplified collision that just works in this case (circle always comes from the bottom)
            const topOfBallIsAboveBottomOfRect = circle.y - circle.radius <= rect.y + rect.height / 2
            const bottomOfBallIsBelowTopOfRect = circle.y + circle.radius >= rect.y - rect.height / 2
            const ballIsRightOfRectLeftSide = circle.x + circle.radius >= rect.x - rect.width / 2
            const ballIsLeftOfRectRightSide = circle.x - circle.radius <= rect.x + rect.width / 2
            return topOfBallIsAboveBottomOfRect && bottomOfBallIsBelowTopOfRect && ballIsRightOfRectLeftSide && ballIsLeftOfRectRightSide
        }
        console.warn(`there is no collision function defined for a ${a.collision} and a ${b.collision}`)
        return undefined
    }
}

class Ball extends Entity {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super(x, y)
        this.collision = 'circle'
        this.speed = 300 // px per second
        this.radius = 10 // radius in px
    }

    update({deltaTime}) {
        this.y -= this.speed * deltaTime / 1000 // deltaTime is ms so we divide by 1000
    }

    /** @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context */
    draw(context) {
        context.beginPath()
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        context.fill()
    }

    isDead(player) {
        const outOfBounds = this.y < 0 - this.radius
        const collidesWithPlayer = Entity.testCollision(player, this)
        return outOfBounds || collidesWithPlayer
    }
}

class Paddle extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super(150, 50)
        this.collision = 'rect'
        this.speed = 200
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 10
    }

    update({deltaTime, inputs}) {
        this.x += this.speed * deltaTime / 1000 * inputs.direction
    }

    /** @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context */
    draw(context) { 
        context.beginPath()
        context.rect(this.x - this.width / 2, this.y - this.height / 2, this.width, this.height)
        context.fill()
    }

    isDead() { return false }
}

class InputsManager {
    constructor() {
        this.direction = 0
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeydown.bind(this))
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyup.bind(this))
    }

    onKeydown(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                this.direction = -1
                break
            case 'ArrowRight':
                this.direction = 1
                break
        }
    }

    onKeyup(event) {
        switch (event.key) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                if(this.direction === -1) 
                    this.direction = 0
                break
            case 'ArrowRight':
                this.direction = 1
                if(this.direction === 1)
                    this.direction = 0
                break
        }
    }
}

class Game {
    /** @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas */
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.entities = [] // contains all game entities (Balls, Paddles, ...)
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        this.newBallInterval = 500 // ms between each ball
        this.lastBallCreated = -Infinity // timestamp of last time a ball was launched
    }

    start() {
        this.lastUpdate = performance.now()
        this.player = new Paddle()
        this.entities.push(this.player)
        this.inputsManager = new InputsManager()
        this.loop()
    }

    update() {
        // calculate time elapsed
        const newTime = performance.now()
        const deltaTime = newTime - this.lastUpdate

        // update every entity
        const frameData = {
            deltaTime,
            inputs: this.inputsManager,
        }
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.update(frameData))

        // other update logic (here, create new entities)
        if(this.lastBallCreated + this.newBallInterval < newTime) {
            const ball = new Ball(this.player.x, 300)
            this.entities.push(ball)
            this.lastBallCreated = newTime
        }

        // remember current time for next update
        this.lastUpdate = newTime
    }

    draw() {
        this.entities.forEach(entity => entity.draw(this.context))
    }

    cleanup() {
        // to prevent memory leak, don't forget to cleanup dead entities
        this.entities.forEach(entity => {
            if(entity.isDead(this.player)) {
                const index = this.entities.indexOf(entity)
                this.entities.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    }

    loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.context.canvas.width, this.context.canvas.height)
            this.update()
            this.draw()
            this.cleanup()
            this.loop()
        })
    }
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const game = new Game(canvas)
game.start()
```

```html
<canvas height="300" width="300"></canvas>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Once you click "Run code snippet", you have to click on the iframe to focus it so it can listen for keyboard inputs (arrow left, arrow right).

Comment: @AGrush tell me if you need something more from this, or if there is anything unclear in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for this.. question.. where do you put the keydown and keyup event listeners so can they affect both ball and paddle classes? I'm assuming having two event listeners is a bad practice.. class structure spins me out. Also, I'm using game.paddleMiddle from inside the game class to move the paddle.. is that ok? https://codepen.io/agrushevskiy/pen/PozzVxV

Comment: yep completely stuck on where to put key&mouse click event listeners

Comment: There are many things to address, I'll edit my post a few times in a row ;)

Comment: amazing thank you so much.. just been looking at this https://github.com/dwmkerr/spaceinvaders/blob/master/js/spaceinvaders.js
why is he using functions as classes for his game and then adding methods to those functions using the prototype chain? is this a code smell??

Comment: @AGrush not a code smell at all. It's an old school way of doing the same thing. `Class` is just a more recent way of writing it but in the end it does the same thing. It creates a "scope" (an object really) where you can store variables and functions.

Comment: @AGrush I updated the code to include an explanation for managing keyboard inputs (which you can expand to manage any sort of input).

Comment: @AGrush I've added collision detection as a bit of an explainer on how to go about adding anything to this example. As I said in the beginning, it's all about separation of concerns (for maintainability) and passing data around (to actually make it work). That's why I like classes: neat little boxes to put stuff in. Good luck.

Comment: this is legendary!

Comment: nice! i think i'll learn more from this than a whole book on JS lol! https://codepen.io/agrushevskiy/pen/PozzVxV

Comment: @AGrush this is looking nice ;-)

Comment: man i'm really stuck i need the enemy to run isDead(true) when ball isDead(true).. as you can't do collision detection on both as i've realized one disappears before the other so when the ball is fast the enemy square doesn't die.. https://codepen.io/agrushevskiy/pen/PozzVxV

Comment: if you change the this.newBallInterval to 700 or more it works.. so weird

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461674/game-loop-failing-when-speed-of-ball-is-faster